# How to move around single elements

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

In the picture attached, I would like to either move the letters A B and the arrow up a little, so they are centered, relative to the tree (tikz-qtree) next to it, or move the tree down a bit. I'm new to all of this and am completely lost. How would I go about this?

[image]

The code I've used for what is depictured is:

```
My MWE:

\documentclass[naustrian]{univie-ling-paper}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem} %Flexible enumerates/itemizes

\usepackage{tikz} %for all basic options
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} %for simple tree syntax
\usepgflibrary{arrows} %for arrow endings
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart} %for structured nodes
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{56}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 


\begin{document}

\begin{example} Merge \newline 
    A \ \ \  B \ \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=40pt]
    \Tree [.C [.A  ] [.B  ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Edit: included MWE

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I added a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since I haven't document class, which you use, I use `article`. IN MWE below I remove all to problem not related package in your MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} %for simple tree syntax

\begin{document}
(1) Merge 
\begin{center}
    $A \quad B \quad\rightarrow \quad$
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=40pt, 
                        baseline=(current bounding box.center) % <---
                        ]
    \Tree [.C [.A  ] [.B  ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```